# higher-end notebook with a track-point

Tags: laptop

My old notebook won't last much longer. I'm looking for a higher-end notebook that will run Ubuntu out of the box. Unfortunately, a trackpoint mouse is absolutely mandatory for me. I know almost all Dell Latitudes have one, but which other do (except for the Thinkpads)?

Does anyone have more information/experience on which notebooks do have a trackpoint and which don't?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because broad, open-ended, opinion-based hardware recommendations are off topic. You can ask on [HardwareRecs.SE] though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Thinkpads run excellent with Linux, even faster than with windows.
The trackpoint, suspend on lid closing, wifi, webcam, everything but the fingerprint reader works.